# Mobilefirst 6.3 push notification isn working on an ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

im working in a mobile hybrid app for android and ios and the push notifications works fine in android and iphone (tested on iphones 5+ and ios 9+), but when tested in a ipad 2.2 ios 8+, ive tested with and without and ipad environment but alway returns this error when im registering push notifications from my devices:

```
 Error in registration for Push notifications, check your provisioning profile. Original error: falta la clave de autorización "aps-environment" válida para la aplicación
```

Is there any diference between iphone and ipad environments if ive only have iphone environment??

Comment: did you register your iPad device under your provisioning profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive just update the ipad to ios 9.2.1 and solve my problem